# My program is not reading integers correctly. Why?

Tags: c, input

I was wondering if somebody could lend me a hand and point out what I am doing wrong here. My task is:

> Write a program that reads integers until 0 is entered. After input terminates, the
>   program should report the total number of even integers (excluding the 0) entered, the
>   average value of the even integers, the total number of odd integers entered, and the
>   average value of the odd integers

I managed to do a similar task but with characters (stopping at '#' instead of 0) and I didn't have issues. What I am not seeing here or missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int evenQ = 0, oddQ = 0, evenSum = 0, oddSum = 0; /* We initate variables */
int ch;

int main(void)
{
    while ((ch = getchar()) != 0 ) /* As long as the input is not 0 keep taking input*/
    {
        if (ch % 2 == 0) /* If the input is an even integer */
        {
            evenQ++; /* Add 1 to evenQ */
            evenSum += ch; /*Add the inputted int to evenSum */
        }
        else
        {
            oddQ++; /* Add 1 to oddQ */
            oddSum += ch; /* Add the inputted int to oddSum */
        }
    }

    printf("Total even integers:\t%d\n"
            "Total odd integers:\t%d\n"
            "Average even ints:\t%d\n"
            "Average odd ints:\t%d\n", evenQ, oddQ, (evenSum/evenQ), (oddSum/oddQ)); /* Print back
            the evenQ, oddQ and the averages of even integers and odd integers
            */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you know what `getchar` function does?

Comment: Use `scanf()` to read integers, not `getchar()`.

Comment: Your program is reading *characters*, not integers.  It might sorta, kinda work for single-character inputs like `'2'` or `'7'`, but presumably you'd also like the user to be able to type multi-digit numbers like `123`.

Comment: *"I managed to do a similar task but with characters"* - Not the same task, so not the same solution. `getchar` isn't the right tool for this task.

Comment: Oh, I thought getchar could also read integers. So it's only a matter of using scanf()? Is there a smaller/simpler function for doing that? (Aka: Do we all use scanf() to read integers or is there any other way?)

Comment: `scanf` is the superficially easy way.  But `scanf` is useless for real programs (and only barely useful, with lots of caveats and possibilities for error, in "toy" programs).  The more robust way to read input like this is to read lines of text using `fgets`, then if you need (say) integers, convert the strings to ints using `atoi()` (or some more powerful function if you want better control over what happens if the user happens to enter something that's not properly a string of digits).

Comment: @SteveSummit with `long tmp = strtol(..); if (!errno && INT_MIN <= tmp && tmp <= INT_MAX) myint = (int)tmp;` The reason being `atoi` is another "toy program" function -- it provides zero error checking to validate conversions....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is dued to `getchar` only pick up chars, not integer (if you input 1, getchar will pick up '1' -char, not int-). Use `scanf` instead of `getchar` like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int evenQ = 0, oddQ = 0, evenSum = 0, oddSum = 0; /* We initate variables */
int ch;

int main(void)
{
    while ((scanf("%i", &ch) == 1) && (ch != 0 )) /* As long as the input is not 0 keep taking input*/
    {
        if (ch % 2 == 0) /* If the input is an even integer */
        {
            evenQ++; /* Add 1 to evenQ */
            evenSum += ch; /*Add the inputted int to evenSum */
        }
        else
        {
            oddQ++; /* Add 1 to oddQ */
            oddSum += ch; /* Add the inputted int to oddSum */
        }
    }

    printf("Total even integers:\t%d\n"
            "Total odd integers:\t%d\n"
            "Average even ints:\t%d\n"
            "Average odd ints:\t%d\n", evenQ, oddQ, (evenSum/evenQ), (oddSum/oddQ)); /* Print back
            the evenQ, oddQ and the averages of even integers and odd integers
            */

    return 0;
}
```

Other example (worst way, but more visual):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int evenQ = 0, oddQ = 0, evenSum = 0, oddSum = 0; /* We initate variables */
int ch = -1;

int main(void)
{
    while (ch != 0 ) /* As long as the input is not 0 keep taking input*/
    {
        scanf("%i", &ch);

        if (ch != 0) // Do not take in care int 0
        {
            if (ch % 2 == 0) /* If the input is an even integer */
            {
                evenQ++; /* Add 1 to evenQ */
                evenSum += ch; /*Add the inputted int to evenSum */
            }
            else
            {
                oddQ++; /* Add 1 to oddQ */
                oddSum += ch; /* Add the inputted int to oddSum */
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Total even integers:\t%d\n"
            "Total odd integers:\t%d\n"
            "Average even ints:\t%d\n"
            "Average odd ints:\t%d\n", evenQ, oddQ, (evenSum/evenQ), (oddSum/oddQ)); /* Print back
            the evenQ, oddQ and the averages of even integers and odd integers
            */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hm... yes but you are including `0` in the "even" numbers.

Comment: @WeatherVane But does it stop when reading 0, or it reads 0, adds to even and then it stops?

Comment: @EmannuelWeg With the new update of the answer, 0 is not taked

Comment: @chux oh, thanks by the advice. I have already updated answer. Why is infinite in `EOF`? (´(scanf("%i", &ch)´ in `EOF` should return `0` and it is `false`, isn't it?